# Transfer data from a TextBox to another TextBox on another page in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm new in ASP.NET and I have to make a project in ASP.NET Web Application in Visual Studio and database in Microsoft SQL Server for finishing my studies at university.
I tried to transfer data from a TextBox to another TextBox, but in another page and this error appears everytime.
I tried using method with Application[] and Session[], but it doesn't work.

Here is my error:

> "System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'"

The code in the first page is :

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=LARI-LUCAS;Initial
    Catalog = Licenta_BD; Integrated Security = True");
SqlCommand cmd;           

try
{
    cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Date_studenti_UPT (universitate,facultate,sectie,nume,prenume,gen,an,media,marca,numar) values(@universitate,@facultate,@sectie,@nume,@prenume,@gen,@an,@media,@marca,@numar) ", conn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@universitate", txtUniv.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@facultate", txtFac.Text.Trim());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sectie", txtSectie.Text.Trim());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nume", txtNume.Text.Trim());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prenume", txtPrenume.Text.Trim());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gen", txtGen.Text.Trim());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@an", txtAn.Text.Trim());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@media", txtMedie.Text.Trim());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@marca", txtMarca.Text.Trim());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@numar", txtNr.Text.Trim());

    int rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    Session["Nume"] = txtNume.Text;
    Session["Prenume"] = txtPrenume.Text;
    Session["Gen"] = txtGen.Text;
    Session["An"] = txtAn.Text;
    Session["Media"] = txtMedie.Text;
    Session["Universitate"] = txtUniv.Text;

    if (rowsAffected == 1)
    {
        conn.Open();
        string url = "Profil.aspx";
        Response.Redirect(url);
    }
    else
        Label12.Text = "Eroare actualizare date utilizator!";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //log error
        Label12.Text = "Eroare la deschidere baza date " + ex.Message;
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
```

And for the page 2 is:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtA.Text = Session["An"].ToString();
    txtG.Text = Session["Gen"].ToString();
    txtM.Text = Session["Media"].ToString();
    txtN.Text = Session["Nume"].ToString();
    txtP.Text = Session["Prenume"].ToString();
    txtUn.Text = Session["Universitate"].ToString();
}
```

Comment: You really shouldn't be starting a new project of any kind in ASP .NET Webforms. It's been obsolete for years.

Comment: It's a project in ASP.NET Web Application. :)

Comment: Does [this](https://forums.asp.net/t/2096848.aspx?Session+variables+lost+after+the+call+of+Response+Redirect+method) help?

Comment: No, it doesn't, but that's it. I cannot do the app in something else..

Comment: So your config allows cookies and stuff? Response.Redirect sends a 302 to the browser, and generally uses cookies. But the cookies might not have been set so they get lost. That's why cookiesless set to true for that one.

Comment: Yes, it works at that point. I receive that error only when i try to transfer data from a textbox to another one with the method Application["'] or Session[""].

Comment: You missed the point of the comment from @DanielMann .You're creating an ASP.NET Web Forms application in 2021. It's obsolete. It's dead. The template you used may have been "ASP.NET Web Application", but you're clearly using Web Forms. Why? Did you choose this template? Do you have an option to switch to a better platform?

Comment: @mason , no, i don't have an option to switch to a better platform, i have to do the app like this.. Ok, maybe you're right and ASP.NET Web Forms is dead in 2021, but i can't do anything.

Comment: Ok, you have to break this down into two parts. Does the database update and adding of the record work ok. Does the data show up in the database? That part has to be working before you move on to the 2nd part (passing the values).

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal yes, the data show up in database.

Comment: Ok, then session seems to be the issue. on the 2nd page load - session() values are thus not working? Add Session["Test"] = "Hello" - and then grab this value on target page - does that work?

Comment: Where does the error show up, which line?

Comment: issue is still exist? Seems like it’s a old question?

Answer (score 0):

I'd use Server.Transfer to redirect to the second page, that way you can call your textbox from page 1 easily.